# Syntax for Accessing Dereferenced Values of an Object

Tags: c++, pointers

In the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
   public:
    int *a, *b;
}
```

```
Foo::Foo(int x, int y) : a( new int ( x ) ) , b( new int ( y ) )
{
}
```

```
Foo test(1,2);
```

If I want to cout the derefereced value stored in pointer variable `a`, why do I write:

```
std::cout << *test.a << std::endl; //method 1
```

and not:

```
std::cout << test.(*a) << std::endl; //method 2
```

It would seem to me that we are accessing the dereferenced value of `a` i.e. `*a`, and this is a member variable of the `test` object of class `Foo` so method 2 feels more syntactically correct. Method 1 (the correct way I believe) appears to dereference the whole `test` object.

Comment: Because language is like that?

Comment: I think this statement is incorrect: *"Method 1 appears to dereference the whole test object"*. I believe it only dereferences the `a` member. `test.a` yields an `int` pointer, and the dereference operator `*` has low precedent, so `*test.a` is like writing `*(test.a)`. Unrolling it may make it a bit more clear: `int *aa = test.a`. That naturally leads to `*aa` to print the integer.

Comment: What's the motivation behind having pointers to something trivial like an `int`? The pointer is larger than the `int` itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you need `*test.a` instead of `test.(*a)` is because `a` itself does't exist (from a variable in scope perspective).  It's a member of `Foo` so to access `Foo::a` you need `test.a`.  Then you apply `*` to `test.a` since `test.a` is a pointer.

Comment: This is related to the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) which C++ inherits from C.